# How I can control flow of execution in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

If you have ever used Window.alert("msg"); API in GWT to show popup, I am not sure but the call to this API pauses the code execution until a user action is taken (cliking the ok button), Simillar to that i have created a custom popup, when it is shown i don't want the code to execute further till any user input in received on the popup, How can i pause the code execution further?
Assume :- 
//Some Code

MY Popup (Here i want to wait till a user action is received.)

//Some code

I read somewhere to use Synchronized key word but that didn't work either,Do you have answer to this. How GWT compiler sees "Synchronized" keyword does it ignores the keyword?

Comment: I have no idea what you try to say. Maybe add some code...

Comment: Hey knarf please let me know if you need more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Create something like a ConfirmCallBack that you fire when the "OK" button (or whatever) is clicked in the popuppanel.

```
//method in your own popup class
public static void confirm(String message,  ConfirmCallBack confirmCallBack)
{
    Button confirmButton = new Button(confirmButtonText, event ->
  {
     confirmCallBack.callback(true);
     //hide popup
  });
}
```

Than also have the ConfirmCallBack interface like

```
public interface ConfirmCallBack
{
   void callback(boolean result);
}
```

Then call your own popup like

```
MyPopup.confirm("Hello world", result ->
{
   if (result)
   {
      //my code to be executed after clicking the ok button
   }
}
```